# Python catch runtime errortype

Tags: python, try-catch

Like to catch SNMPerror, if error occur, do something.

Python code to fetch Network OS type via snmphandler package. It works, but if the SNMP is not query the request, it will timeout. I would like to catch that and print "No SNMP Active"

```
from nelsnmp.snmp import SnmpHandler
from nelsnmp.errors import ArgumentError, SnmpError
def findnetOS(host):
    dev = SnmpHandler(host=host, version='2c', community='public')
    hostinfo = HostInfo(dev)
    osversion = hostinfo.get_version()
    try:
       os = hostinfo.os
    except ArgumentError as e:
       if e.__str__() == "No valid SNMP version defined":
          os = None
          return os
    else:
       return os

ostype = findnetOS(host)
if ostype != None:
   ostype = "cisco_"+ostype
   print ostype
else:
   print "No SNMP Active"
   exit(-1)
```

Expected output should be print "No SNMP Active" when error occurs and print ostype when it runs thru without errors.

Error I get:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nelsnmp/snmp.py", line 210, in _raise_error
    raise ErrorType(error_data)
nelsnmp.errors.SnmpError: No SNMP response received before timeout
```

Thank you for the view

Comment: You're catching `ArgumentError` instead of `SnmpError`.

Comment: You didn't show us complete error traceback, only the last lines.

Comment: I tried using SnmpError, but some reason it is not catching and it runs thru the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the same thing you're doing for the `ArgumentError`

```
from nelsnmp.snmp import SnmpHandler
from nelsnmp.errors import ArgumentError, SnmpError
def findnetOS(host):
    try:
        dev = SnmpHandler(host=host, version='2c', community='public')
        hostinfo = HostInfo(dev)
        osversion = hostinfo.get_version()
    except SnmpError as e:
       # handle your error here
       pass
    try:
       os = hostinfo.os
    except ArgumentError as e:
       if e.__str__() == "No valid SNMP version defined":
          os = None
          return os
    else:
       return os

ostype = findnetOS(host)
if ostype != None:
   ostype = "cisco_"+ostype
   print ostype
else:
   print "No SNMP Active"
   exit(-1)
```

Comment: Worth noting for OP, if it's relevant: you're also allowed to chain multiple `except` blocks on a single `try`, one after another, to handle different types of errors differently.